# elasticdump is not migrating index - total writes 0

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to import index from json file to elasticsearch server but it is failing.

Specifications:
elasticsearch : 4.10.3
elasticdump : 2.4.2

command I am using

```
elasticdump --input=/home/ubuntu/Files/stocks.json --output=http://localhost:9200/ --type=data`
```

My stocks.json file looks like

`{"_index":"stocks","_type":"stock","_id":"AVhKm5L8FPDye23IuJqe","_score":1,"_source":{"name":"Sun Pharmaceutical Industries Ltd.","industry":"PHARMA","isin":"INE044A01036","symbol":"SUNPHARMA","tweet":"sun pharma' OR 'SUNPHARMA'"}}
{"_index":"stocks","_type":"stock","_id":"AVhKm5L8FPDye23IuJqV","_score":1,"_source":{"name":"Tata Steel Ltd.","industry":"METALS","isin":"INE081A01012","symbol":"TATASTEEL","tweet":"tata steel' OR 'TATASTEEL'"}}
{"_index":"stocks","_type":"stock","_id":"AVhKm5L7FPDye23IuJp2","_score":1,"_source":{"name":"ICICI Bank Ltd.","industry":"FINANCIAL SERVICES","isin":"INE090A01021","symbol":"ICICIBANK","tweet":"icici bank' OR 'ICICIBANK'"}}`

I am getting following message

```
Sat, 07 Oct 2017 05:46:52 GMT | starting dump
Sat, 07 Oct 2017 05:46:52 GMT | got 100 objects from source file 
(offset: 0)
Sat, 07 Oct 2017 05:46:52 GMT | sent 100 objects to destination 
elasticsearch, wrote 0
Sat, 07 Oct 2017 05:46:52 GMT | got 0 objects from source file  
(offset: 100)
Sat, 07 Oct 2017 05:46:52 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Sat, 07 Oct 2017 05:46:52 GMT | dump complete
```

I had used same json file before but somehow this is not working in this new server. I have installed elasticsearch, node recently in this server.

Thanks for help

J

Comment: What errors do you get in the ES server logs ?

Comment: Thanks for reply... There is no error in logs and I am not getting errors while importing..It's just say total writes 0

Comment: ES 4.10.3 doesn't exist. What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200` ?

Comment: {
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Ikthalon",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.3",
    "build_hash" : "NA",
    "build_timestamp" : "NA",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: i was giving lucene version which keeps changing, so I believe it is 1.7.3

Comment: Then you need to use a 1.x version of elasticdump, 2.4.2 is for ES 2.x

Comment: I uninstalled elasticsearch from my server and installed latest version 5.6.2 of elastic search. But on executing  `curl -XGET localhost:9200` , I am still getting version as 1.7.3.(similar reply as posted above). Not sure about this

Comment: Ok..Now I got elasticsearch version 5.6.2 and elasticdump 3.3.1 on my machine and still getting the same error.....Total writes 0